# {:error, {:undefined, :standard_syntax_parser, ['syntax error before: ', []]}}

Tags: erlang, yecc

So I am trying to use yecc.

```
Terminals string string_delimeter.

Nonterminals value string_content.

Rootsymbol value.

value -> string : extract_value('$1').

value -> string_delimeter string_content string_delimeter : '$2'.
string_content -> value string_content : ['$1' | '$2'].
string_content -> value : '$1'.

Erlang code.

extract_value({_, Value}) -> Value.
```

For the input:

```
[string_delimeter: '\'', string: 'test', string_delimeter: '\'']
```

I get

```
{:error, {:undefined, :standard_syntax_parser, ['syntax error before: ', []]}}
```

If I delete any (left or right) string_delimeter surrounding string_content:

```
value -> string_delimeter string_content string_delimeter : '$2'.

value -> string_delimeter string_content : '$2'.
```

for

```
[string_delimeter: '\'', string: 'test']
```

it returns

```
{:ok, 'test'}
```

I don't really understand this behaviour, where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not figure why this is a problem in yecc:
token_1 token_2 token_1
I really wish I would know, but I have a way around this:

```
Terminals string string_delimeter whitespace.


Nonterminals value string_content.


Rootsymbol value.

value -> string : extract_value('$1').

value -> string_delimeter string_content : '$2'.
string_content -> string_content string_delimeter : '$1'.
string_content -> value whitespace string_content : ['$1' | '$3'].
string_content -> value : ['$1'].

Erlang code.

extract_value({_, Value}) -> Value.
```

Comment: *this is a problem in yecc:  `[token1, token2, token1]`* -- Hey, you're right!  I thought it was only single quotes that was the problem.   I can't parse the following:  `:string_parser.parse([{:a, 1}, {:content, 1, "hello"}, {:a, 1}])` => 
`{:error, {1, :string_parser, ['syntax error before: ', []]}}`.  Same error as with a single quote.

Comment: But...I can parse `[token1, token2, token1]` -- even with single quotes for token1--if I write a non-recursive parser: `:string_parser.parse([{:"'", 1}, {:content, 1, "hello"}, {:"'", 1}])` => `{:ok, "hello"}`

Answer (score 0):

> For the input:
>
> ```
> [string_delimeter: '\'', string: 'test', string_delimeter: '\'']
> ```

I think you are confused (or maybe it's me!).  `yecc` expects a list of tokens, where a token is a 2 or 3 element tuple.  From the [yecc docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html):

> The user should implement a scanner that segments the input text, and
>   turns it into one or more lists of tokens. Each token should be a
>   tuple containing information about syntactic category, position in the
>   text (e.g. line number), and the actual terminal symbol found in the
>   text: `{Category, LineNumber, Symbol}`.
>
> If a terminal symbol is the only member of a category, and the symbol
>   name is identical to the category name, the token format may be
>   `{Symbol, LineNumber}`...

Here's an example of what yecc expects:

```
[
     {'[',1},
     {atom,1,foo},
     {',',1},
     {'[',1},
     {int,1,1},
     {']',1},
     {',',1},
     {'[',1},
     {atom,1,bar},
     {',',1},
     {'[',1},
     {int,1,2},
     {',',1},
     {int,1,3}, 
     {']',1},
     {']',1},
     {']',1}
]
```

You can implement such a scanner with `leex`, then feed the output to your `yecc` parser.

A word of advice: you should never post a question describing how you ran your code--it's just a big waste of time.  Instead copy and paste the exact commands you ran as well as the output those commands produced.  All you have to say is:

> 1. This is what I tried:
>
> [Your code here]
>
> 2. Here is the output:
>
> [all commands you ran and the output here]
>
> 3. This is the output I expect/want, or Wtf??!! is going on.
>
> [expected/desired output here]

Comment: I'm using leex, and I added the TokenLine, no difference. From what I see I can't do: token_1 token_2 token_1 -> etc. Bummer, how could I handle foobarfoo when I want foo.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, okay.  You are using `elixir` even though the tags on your question say that you are using `erlang`.  I can get a simpler version of your parser to work:

string_parser.yrl:

```
Nonterminals the_string content.
Terminals '\'' string.
Rootsymbol the_string.

the_string -> '\'' content '\'' : '$2'.

%I guess the atom :string has to be the first element of the tuple
%returned by '$2' in previous line:
content -> string : extract_value('$1')

Erlang code.

extract_value({_, _, Value}) -> Value.
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> :yecc.file('string_parser.yrl')  
{:ok, 'string_parser.erl'}

iex(2)> c("string_parser.erl")
[:string_parser]

iex(3)> :string_parser.parse([{:"'", 1}, {:string, 1, "hello"}, {:"'", 1}])
{:ok, "hello"}
```

But, I cannot get a recursive definition to work.

Okay, I'm getting closer:

string_parser.yrl:

```
Nonterminals string interior_strings interior_string.
Terminals left_delim right_delim result.
Rootsymbol string.

string -> left_delim interior_strings right_delim : '$2'.
string -> left_delim right_delim : "".

interior_strings -> interior_string : ['$1'].
interior_strings -> interior_string interior_strings : ['$1' | '$2'].

interior_string -> result : extract_value('$1').
interior_string -> string : '$1'.

Erlang code.

extract_value({_, _, Value}) -> Value.
```

In iex:

```
iex(49)> :yecc.file('string_parser.yrl')
{:ok, 'string_parser.erl'}

iex(50)> c("string_parser.erl")
[:string_parser]    

iex(51)> :string_parser.parse([{:left_delim, 1}, {:result, 1, "hello"}, {:left_delim, 1}, {:result, 1, "goodbye"}, {:right_delim, 1}, {:right_delim, 1}])
{:ok, ["hello", ["goodbye"]]}

iex(53)>
```

At this point, I don't know why the blasted brackets are around `"goodbye"`.

Success!

string_parser.yrl:

```
Nonterminals string interior_strings interior_string.
Terminals left_delim right_delim result.
Rootsymbol string.

string -> left_delim interior_strings right_delim : '$2'.
string -> left_delim right_delim : "".

interior_strings -> left_delim interior_string right_delim: ['$2'].
interior_strings -> interior_string interior_strings : ['$1' | '$2'].

interior_string -> result : extract_value('$1').
interior_string -> string : '$1'.

Erlang code.

extract_value({_, _, Value}) -> Value.
```

In iex:

```
iex(53)> :yecc.file('string_parser.yrl') 
{:ok, 'string_parser.erl'}  

iex(54)> c("string_parser.erl")
[:string_parser] 

iex(55)> :string_parser.parse([{:left_delim, 1}, {:result, 1, "hello"}, {:left_delim, 1}, {:result, 1, "goodbye"}, {:right_delim, 1}, {:right_delim, 1}])
{:ok, ["hello", "goodbye"]}
```

The one thing I still can't get to work is if I explicitly specify `'\''` for the delimiter:

```
Nonterminals string interior_strings interior_string.
Terminals '\'' result.
Rootsymbol string.
Endsymbol '$end'.

string -> '\'' interior_strings '\'' : '$2'.
string -> '\'' '\'' : "".

interior_strings -> '\'' interior_string '\'': ['$2'].
interior_strings -> interior_string interior_strings : ['$1' | '$2'].

interior_string -> result : extract_value('$1').
interior_string -> string : '$1'.

Erlang code.

extract_value({_, _, Value}) -> Value.
```

In iex:

```
iex(3)> :string_parser.parse([{:"'", 1}, {:result, 1, "hello"}, 
{:"'", 1}, {:result, 1, "goodbye"}, {:"'", 1}, {:"'", 1}, {:"$end", 1}])  

{:error, {1, :string_parser, ['syntax error before: ', []]}}
```

It's too frustrating to work with such horrible error messages.  There's a syntax error before an empty list `[]`??!  Where is the empty list in the list of tokens?

I thought that adding a last tuple: `{:"$end", 1}` might work -- but no luck.  Same error.

I can get the string_parser to work if I use literal brackets as the delimiters:

string_parser.yrl:

```
Nonterminals string interior_strings interior_string.
Terminals '[' ']' content.
Rootsymbol string.

string -> '[' interior_strings ']' : '$2'.
string -> '[' ']' : "".

interior_strings -> '[' interior_string ']' : ['$2'].
interior_strings -> interior_string interior_strings : ['$1' | '$2'].

interior_string -> content : extract_content('$1').
interior_string -> string : '$1'.

Erlang code.

extract_content({_, _, Content}) -> Content.
```

In iex:

```
iex(11)> :yecc.file('string_parser.yrl')
{:ok, 'string_parser.erl'}  

iex(12)> c("string_parser.erl") 
[:string_parser]    

iex(13)> :string_parser.parse([{:"[", 1}, {:content, 1, "hello"}, {:"[", 1}, {:content, 1, "goodbye"}, {:"]", 1}, {:"]", 1}])

{:ok, ["hello", "goodbye"]}
iex(14)>
```

I tried writing a string_parser in erlang, and I got the same error.  The .yrl files are not erlang syntax, so whatever is parsing the .yrl files does not seem to be able to parse a single quote atom: `'\''`.